# Arrow icon in the keyboard like snapchat app - Android EditText

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext, snapchat

I need to store the user input in an EditText after the user write something and clicks the blue keyboard button (on the bottom right of the keyboard). Instead of the classic check icon I would prefer an arrow icon like the one in the snapchat app in the text field for "normal" messages. Anyone knows how to do that? I guess it depends on the value of the `android:inputType` attribute in the xml file, but I can't find any values that make the keyboard have that arrow icon.

Comment: Set `inputType` to `text` and `imeOptions` to `actionGo`.

Comment: What i was looking for was `actionSend`, but I didn't know about `imeOptions`. Thank you very much.